# mariadb / mysql wont change table_cache / table_open_cache

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've configured my i7 64gb ssd server with centos7 with the following my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
key_buffer = 12M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
table_cache = 4096
table_open_cache = 4096
table_definition_cache = 4096
sort_buffer_size = 48M
read_buffer_size = 32M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 104M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 100M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 1024m
#myisam_max_extra_sort_file_size = 1024m
myisam_repair_threads = 1
thread_cache_size = 32
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 512M
query_cache_limit = 8M
max_connections=50
wait_timeout=60
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
#innodb_io_capacity = 400
#innodb_read_io_threads = 8
#innodb_write_io_threads = 8
#innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 24M
```

But when i run mysql_tuner.pl
i still get

```
TABLE CACHE
Current table_open_cache = 482 tables
Current table_definition_cache = 4096 tables
You have a total of 1027 tables
You have 482 open tables.
Current table_cache hit rate is 15%
, while 100% of your table cache is in use
You should probably increase your table_cache
```

Of course i restarted my mariadb instance. but i have no clue.
Search turned up empty as well.

Hope someone could help out Cheers.

Comment: Do you see `Opened_table` incrementing as time passes? You could check with `mysqladmin -r -i 5 extended-status | grep Opened`. 

What is max number of file descriptors that mysqld user can opend? You could check with `ulimit -a | grep files`.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system has a low limit.  In Unix, see `ulimit -n`, and change it.  Some versions have an unnecessarily low limit of 1024.

Most, but not all, things set by my.cnf (my.ini) stay set.  `table_open_cache` is one that is changed based on the environment.  Use `SHOW VARIABLES` to see the real values.  Or `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'table_open_cache'` to see the one setting.